# screen recorder in react 16.34

Tags: reactjs, type-conversion, screen-capture

I am developing project with react.js 16.3.
I want to get screen record using use-screen-recording module.
but screen-recording module supported in react ^17.0.1.
[image: this is result]

my code:

```js
....
import useScreenRecording from "use-screen-recording";

class ... extends Component {
  .....
  render(){
    const { isRecording, recording, toggleRecording } = useScreenRecording();
    
    
    return(
      <div className = "question mb-5" >
        <div className = "row" >
          <div className = "col-md-8 m-auto" >
            {/* video capture area */}
            <div>
              <button onClick={toggleRecording}>
                {isRecording ? "Stop" : "Start Recording"}
              </button>

              {!!recording && (
                <video autoPlay src={recording && URL.createObjectURL(recording)} />
              )}
            </div>
            .......
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    )
  }
  
}
```

so I try find another module, I had use several modules: ex):screen recording and RecordRTC modules.
but I can't get any screen.
how do I use modules.

so question is what's module's name suit react 16.x?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. What have you tried? What have you got? Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry, So I had done upgrade my question.